# Error H13 heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

When I upload a file , and send this file to s3 ( 5 MB of csv file ) on heroku I got error H13 ( Connection Cloesed without response). I added a line ( environment.rb and application.rb ) lines:

```
if Rack::Utils.respond_to?("key_space_limit=")
  Rack::Utils.key_space_limit = 262144 # 4 times the default size
end
```

but It did not help me.

My code is:

```
def import_from_csv(csv_file, user, organization, related_object, after_import= nil)
    file_upload = FileUpload.upload_to_s3!(user, csv_file)
   delay.process_csv(file_upload, related_object, organization, after_import)
  end
```

Comment: upload a file on heroku??? it's read only

Comment: He's uploading to S3, @apneadiving... Are you using Unicorn? It could be the timeout setting. However, if you fix that, my guess is that you may end up with an H12 error instead. I'm facing the same issue and so far posting directly to S3 seems to be the only solution.

Comment: Just to correct one thing from @apneadiving, the filesystem isn't read-only, but it is ephemeral. So any files you put into the filesystem will 1. not be accessible to any other dynos and 2. will be lost upon the dyno being restarted or destroyed.

Comment: any solution? we're seeing the same issue.